# XSLT Remove node but keep contents

Tags: xml, xslt, reporting-services

I'm trying to remove a node name, but keep the contents, or copy the contents of a node to it's parent node.  I'm exporting XML from SSRS and have attached an XSLT file to the report RDL. I feel like I'm sooo close with the xslt I have. I'm trying to remove node 'Cell' which is repeated frequently in the file.

I want this:

```
<ReportSectionAPercentLabel>
    <Cell>
        <losPct>0.262158054711246</losPct>
    </Cell>
</ReportSectionAPercentLabel>
```

To look like this:

```
<ReportSectionAPercentLabel>
    <losPct>0.262158054711246</losPct>
</ReportSectionAPercentLabel>
```

This is an excert from the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<Report xmlns="My_Report" Name="My report">
<ReportSectionATablix>
    <ReportSectionARowGroup_Collection>
        <ReportSectionARowGroup>
            <losProvider>Your Enterprise</losProvider>
            <ReportSectionAColumnGroup_Collection>
                <ReportSectionAColumnGroup>
                    <ReportSectionAGroupLabel>07</ReportSectionAGroupLabel>
                    <ReportSectionACountLabel>
                        <Cell>
                            <ReportSectionACount>345</ReportSectionACount>
                        </Cell>
                    </ReportSectionACountLabel>
                    <ReportSectionAPercentLabel>
                        <Cell>
                            <losPct>0.262158054711246</losPct>
                        </Cell>
                    </ReportSectionAPercentLabel>
                </ReportSectionAColumnGroup>
                <ReportSectionAColumnGroup>
                    <ReportSectionAGroupLabel>814</ReportSectionAGroupLabel>
                    <ReportSectionACountLabel>
                        <Cell>
                            <ReportSectionACount>153</ReportSectionACount>
                        </Cell>
                </ReportSectionACountLabel>
                ...
```

This is the XSLT. Do I have the Xpath to Cell wrong?

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" >
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Cell" >
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is the correct one, but the issue is one of namespaces. In your XML, you have a default namespace declaration (the **xmlns**)

```
<Report xmlns="My_Report" Name="My report">
```

This means that element, and all descendants, belong to that namespace (unless overridden by another namespace declaration). However, in your XSLT, where you have specified **Cell** as the template match, this is looking for a **Cell** element in NO namespace, which won't match your **Cell** in the XML with a namespace.

The solution is to declare the namespace in the XSLT too, with a prefix, and use that prefix in matching the **Cell** element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:rep="My_Report">
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*" >
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="rep:Cell" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, if you were using XSLT 2.0, you could use the **xpath-default-namespace**, in which case any Xpath expression without a namespace prefix, is assumed to be in that default namespace

This would also work...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xpath-default-namespace="My_Report">
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*" >
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Cell" >
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If, for whatever reason, you wanted to avoid coding the namespace declaration in your XSLT, you could change the template match to the following:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Cell']" >
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much for the explanation. A) I didn't understand about the namespaces, and B) I now know that instead of using a standard template for the SSRS output I'll need to specify the namespace for each.  Thanks!